# Error with generated hash key facebook android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, hash, key

Yesterday I created an hashkey to log in into facebook through my app. It worked until today when it gave another hashkey that was invalid. I put this hashkey on my app's developers page but still it refuses to work. Any ideas?
[developers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrlh8.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4oyq.png)

Comment: did you make your app public in the app review section?

Comment: @Arpan yes I did.

Comment: Seems that the problem only occurs on one device..

Comment: uninstall and resinstall app

Comment: Tried that already, but doesn't work. Anyway I'll just move on as I've other devices do debug on. Any chance how to isolate the number in an url like: "https://www.facebook.com/app-scoped-user-id/1233829560005693/" ? @ArpanSharma